# Passing String array using intent

Tags: android

i am struck with passing String array from one activity to another using intent. while passing only a String from two activities, its work clear. but whenever i tried to access string array i am getting force close error. can any one guide me to rectify the problem.

Comment: can you show how you doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just the `Intent.setExtra(String, Serializable)` method. It accepts any `Serializable` object. If that does not work, please attach results from your `LogCat`, "Closed unexpectedly" just means your app failed, `LogCat` tells *why* it failed.

Answer (score 0):

use `Parcelable` to do this.

please refer to this link http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/